# AngularJS: How to bind values of options (in select tag) generated with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<select id="vehicleMark" name="vehicleMark" ng-disabled="!checked2" ng-model="mark.vehicleMark">
    <option value=""><c:out value=""/></option>
    <c:forEach items="${markeVozila}" var="marka">
        <option value="${marka}"><c:out value="${marka}"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
<select id="vehicleModel" name="vehicleModel" data-ng-show="mark.vehicleMark != ''" ng-model="vehicleModel">
     <option ng-repeat='model in carModels | filter: mark' value="{{model.modelId}}">
        {{model.vehicleModel}}
     </option>                      
</select>
```

Now, the problem is in the second select that I can't set the value of the options. How can I set the values of the options to the values of my modelId attributes of the model object?

Comment: Do you want to update second option dropdown based on value selected on first optin dropdown..

Comment: please attach fiddle

Comment: better to use `ngOptions` here instead of `ngRepeat`